# Loading new data on page navigation

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Hi I'm sure this is a simple question and I am just missing something

So far my app downloads a JSON file that contains the info that I use to populate a Grouped Item Page.

What I would like to do is when the user picks on one of the items is to use a URL that is part of the item to load another JSON file that contains more info about the specific item that has been chosen and then use the info in this file to create the data for the Item Detail Page and the same when going from the Grouped Detail Page to the Item Detail Page.

Hope this makes sense if you need ay code or more information please just ask me

Thanks in advance,

Chris Foxley-Evans

Comment: Are you working in HTML/JavaScript, or C#/XAML? And are you using the Grid or Split app template?

Comment: I'm working in c#/xaml Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Either way, just specify the page parameter when navigating from Group/Item/Detail Page.

```
private void ViewDetail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FeedItem selectedItem = this.itemListView.SelectedItem as FeedItem;
        if (selectedItem != null && this.Frame != null)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage), selectedItem);
        }   
    }
```

Where e is your Data to pass around the pages.